# what does the hash from `git describe` refer to?

Tags: git, git-describe, git-hash

```
$ git describe --tags --long
test-1-g3c31c73
           \_ ???
```

The `g3c31c73` doesn't seem to point to anything... The [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe) says it's *the abbreviated object name of the most recent commit*, but it's not the HEAD commit hash, and `find .git/objects -type f | grep g3c31c73` finds nothing.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The "g" isn't a part of the commit.

Try looking for a commit `3c31c73` using `git show 3c31c73`.

From the [git-describe doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe#_examples):

> The "g" prefix stands for "git" and is used to allow describing the version of a software depending on the SCM the software is managed with. This is useful in an environment where people may use different SCMs.